# Multi-class classification: good accuracy on validation set but prediction on test set

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to classify images belonging to 16 classes. The images have different geometric shapes ([see Fig. 2](https://www.rp-photonics.com/lp_modes.html)). The training set consists of 16 x 320 = 5120 images, the validation set has 16 x 160 = 2560 images, and the test set has 16 x 2 = 32 images.

I'm using the below code to build the CNN and make predictions.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU 
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers import Activation

num_classes = 16
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(64, 64, 3),padding='same'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))
#classifier.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

classifier.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))                 
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))    

classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

classifier.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))


# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   width_shift_range=0.1, 
                                   height_shift_range=0.1)                              

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = training_set.n//training_set.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_TEST = test_set.n//test_set.batch_size

early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint('model' + '.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                    steps_per_epoch = STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    epochs = 10,
                    validation_data = test_set,
                    validation_steps = STEP_SIZE_TEST,
                    callbacks=[early_stopping_callback, checkpoint_callback],
                    workers = 32)

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')


# Part 3 - making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
for i in range(1,33):
    test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/Image ' + str(i) +'.bmp', target_size = (64, 64))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    #print(model.predict(test_image)[0])
    print(model.predict(test_image)[0].argmax()+1)
```

I'm getting the following result for the training and validation accuracy and loss.

```
Epoch 1/10
160/160 [==============================] - 29s 179ms/step - loss: 1.3693 - acc: 0.5299 - val_loss: 0.1681 - val_acc: 0.9297

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.16809, saving model to model.h5
Epoch 2/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 112ms/step - loss: 0.2668 - acc: 0.8984 - val_loss: 0.0773 - val_acc: 0.9699

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.16809 to 0.07725, saving model to model.h5
Epoch 3/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 111ms/step - loss: 0.1469 - acc: 0.9482 - val_loss: 0.0133 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.07725 to 0.01327, saving model to model.h5
Epoch 4/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 111ms/step - loss: 0.0990 - acc: 0.9650 - val_loss: 0.0147 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.01327
Epoch 5/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 113ms/step - loss: 0.0700 - acc: 0.9740 - val_loss: 7.3014e-04 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.01327 to 0.00073, saving model to model.h5
Epoch 6/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 114ms/step - loss: 0.0545 - acc: 0.9809 - val_loss: 0.0012 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.00073
Epoch 7/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 111ms/step - loss: 0.0374 - acc: 0.9865 - val_loss: 0.0101 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.00073
Epoch 8/10
160/160 [==============================] - 18s 111ms/step - loss: 0.0489 - acc: 0.9832 - val_loss: 0.0200 - val_acc: 0.9992
```

When trying to test the model on the 32 images of the test set, I got only 3 correct predictions. So my questions are:

1) Why I'm getting a good accuracy on validation but the models fails on the test set?

2) How can I display a random sample of the validation set (say 10 images) with their predicted classes, to have an idea how the CNN is doing on the validation set?

3) Any general tips on how to improve the accuracy on the test set?

Any help is appreciated!
Many thanks :)

Comment: validation acc is 1 for some epochs. Possibility for data leak from the train to valid.

Comment: @Sreeram TP : do you happen to have an idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: The 3 datasets are independents. I mean, the images are assigned totally randomly to each of them? If yes, another possibility may be overfitting on the validation set. Try having very few images in the validation set and see how it works. Then gradually increase its size and see if you reach a point where the test set accuracy decreases while the validation accuracy increases. Also, you may try early stopping.

Comment: @DavideVisentin: I'm using early stopping in my code. The thing is that I'm a bit of novice, I don't know if the number of samples is sufficient for the training and the validation. What do you mean by "the images are assigned totally randomly to each of them"? I'm having three folders and I'm putting images in each one of them randomly. Does this make sense?

Comment: Any help with the second question? Thanks :)

Comment: @Jeremy yes it makes sense. The important thing is that you don't put, for example, all cats images in one set and none of them in the other.
Concerning the second question, you already know how the model perform on the validation set. The accuracy is the number of correctly predicted instanced divided by the total number of instances. However, if you want to know the outcome for single images, you can apply the fitted model to each of them, one at a time, and look at the predicted class.

Comment: Thanks @DavideVisentin. I was hoping to see if someone could suggest practical things to solve the issue.

Comment: @Jeremy, have you looked at my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

This could have happened for many reasons, but I will address one which is the difference in data distribution between your train, validation and test sets.

In an ideal situation, you should have your train, validation and test sets come from the same distribution. While this is a concept, in practice it could mean not only the same amount of data points per class, but also among many other dimensions. Such dimension could be the quality of images per splits, i.e. you should avoid having quality images in your train set and valid set, while test set to have low quality images. And there are many more dimensions like this along which distributions ideally should be same.

Therefore it is a game of chances, and you want to avoid a chance of having, on the account of bad luck and no matter how low probable such an event is, ending up with a test set that is different than the rest of the splits.

To overcome this:

1) Choose a different seed while shuffling your data before splitting

2) Choose equal split size for your test and validation sets

3) Use k-fold cross validation

You can do one or any of the above steps alone or in combination. You can read more about  it here:

https://cs230-stanford.github.io/train-dev-test-split.html

Hope this helps